# Run external library that is supposed to target HTML node in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to run flickity "the react way". Here is my component with what i'm trying to achice, this:

```
const ProductCarousel = ({item}) => {
  const flky = new Flickity('.carousel', flickityOptions)
  return (
      <div class='carousel'>
        {item.get('images').map((url) => (
          <img src={stripUrl(url)} className='carousel-cell' width={512} />
      ))}
      </div>)
}
```

This doesn't work and is probably wrong since i'm targeting a node that is created with react. There are multiple npm packages that I could use, but I don't think they will work for me because i need to have access to `flky` to access mehtods in that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `componentDidMount`: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

In your case, you'd put `const flky = new Flickity('.carousel', flickityOptions)` into `componentDidMount`